# Задача на Python которая определяет, является ли натуральное число N простым, не проходит ограничение по времени

Tags: python, pypy

[image: Фото Задачи]

Вот сам код:

```
n=int(input())

counter=0

for i in range(1,n+1):
    if n%i==0:
        counter+=1

if counter>2 or counter == 1:
    print('no')
else:
    print('yes')
```

pypy 3.3(7.3.0) выбирал все равно не прошло

Comment: Вы уже воспользовались поиском по сайту и не обнаружили ни одного аналогичного вопроса?

Comment: 1) На 1 не надо пробовать делить, и так понятно, что делится 2) значит, если хоть на что-то разделилось, то не нужно считать делители дальше, можно сразу выводить ответ и заканчивать цикл 3) перебирать делители можно до корня из числа, а дальше нет смысла, почему - подумайте 4) и да, поищите аналогичные вопросы, их тут полно